# Error On MySQL Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

can anyone help me on why the I can't create the temporary table on the stored procedure.

Here is my stored procedure script

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getProductionItem$$
CREATE DEFINER=pvtuser@`%` PROCEDURE getProductionItem(projectID BIGINT(20))


BEGIN

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempProdItem(
    prodType SET('JOB','BATCH','DOCGROUP'),
    taskQueueId BIGINT(20),
    jobBatchDocId BIGINT(20),
    jobBatchDocName VARCHAR(255),
    lockStatus SET('LOCKED','OPEN')
  );


  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;


  DECLARE prodType VARCHAR(10);
  DECLARE taskQueueId BIGINT(20);
  DECLARE jobBatchDocId BIGINT(20);
  DECLARE jobBatchDocName VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE lockStatus VARCHAR(10);


  DECLARE docCursor CURSOR
      FOR SELECT 'DOCGROUP',
                 jq.taskqueueid,
                 jq.documentgroupid,
                 dgd.documentGroupName,
                 COALESCE(jql.lockStatus,'OPEN')
            FROM jobdetails jd
           INNER JOIN jobqueue jq
              ON jd.jobid=jq.jobid
           INNER JOIN documentgroupdetails dgd
              ON jq.documentgroupid=dgd.documentgroupid
            LEFT JOIN jobqueuelocked jql
              ON jq.taskqueueid=jql.taskqueueid
           GROUP BY jq.taskqueueid;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

  OPEN docCursor;

  Loop1: LOOP
    FETCH docCursor INTO prodType,taskQueueId,jobBatchDocId,jobBatchDocName,lockStatus;
    IF done=1 THEN
      LEAVE Loop1;
    ELSE
       /* TODO INSERT HERE IN TEMP TABLE */
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE docCursor;

  SELECT * FROM tempProdItem;

END

$$
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: 1. Why are you creating a table in the Routine?
2. What happens when you execute the Routine for the second time it is trying to create an already existing Table. So drop it first and create it again.

Comment: What is the exact error please?

Comment: 1. i need temp table to store data on the different cursor result set.

Comment: Here is the exact error: Script line: 4 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;


  DECLARE prodType VARCHAR(10);
  DECLARE task' at line 15

Comment: All DECLARE statements have to be at the begining of the BEGIN-END clause. Place 'CREATE TABLE' statement after the declarations.

Comment: thanks Devart, temp table has been created but when I'm running the above script, an error again encountered on the conditional statement block.. What is that error? Conditional statement looks fine.

Comment: here is the exact error line: Script line: 4 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF;


  END LOOP;

  CLOSE docCursor;

  SELECT * FROM tempProdItem;
' at line 46

Comment: this is now okay, I've just putted the INSERT command on ELSE blocked.. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS getProductionItem$$
CREATE DEFINER=pvtuser@`%` PROCEDURE getProductionItem(projectID BIGINT(20))

BEGIN

  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE prodType VARCHAR(10);
  DECLARE taskQueueId BIGINT(20);
  DECLARE jobBatchDocId BIGINT(20);
  DECLARE jobBatchDocName VARCHAR(255);
  DECLARE lockStatus VARCHAR(10);

  DECLARE docCursor CURSOR
      FOR SELECT 'DOCGROUP',
                 jq.taskqueueid,
                 jq.documentgroupid,
                 dgd.documentGroupName,
                 COALESCE(jql.lockStatus,'OPEN')
            FROM jobdetails jd
           INNER JOIN jobqueue jq
              ON jd.jobid=jq.jobid
           INNER JOIN documentgroupdetails dgd
              ON jq.documentgroupid=dgd.documentgroupid
            LEFT JOIN jobqueuelocked jql
              ON jq.taskqueueid=jql.taskqueueid
           GROUP BY jq.taskqueueid;

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=1;

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempProdItem(
    prodType SET('JOB','BATCH','DOCGROUP'),
    taskQueueId BIGINT(20),
    jobBatchDocId BIGINT(20),
    jobBatchDocName VARCHAR(255),
    lockStatus SET('LOCKED','OPEN')
  );


  OPEN docCursor;

  Loop1: LOOP
    FETCH docCursor INTO prodType,taskQueueId,jobBatchDocId,jobBatchDocName,lockStatus;
    IF done=1 THEN
      LEAVE Loop1;
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO tempProdItem
             (prodType,taskQueueId,jobBatchDocId,jobBatchDocName,lockStatus)
      VALUES (prodType,taskQueueId,jobBatchDocId,jobBatchDocName,lockStatus);
    END IF;

  END LOOP;

  CLOSE docCursor;

  SELECT * FROM tempProdItem;

END

$$
DELIMITER;
```